# Use value of variable inside ready function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got a question regarding using a value from an outside function within a ready function. Perhaps there is a simple solution but I could not find the answer yet.

I want to achieve the following situation. I got these 4 buttons:

```
<a onmouseover="Tip('content1')" class="">Basic text1</a>    
<a onmouseover="Tip('content2')" class="">Basic text2</a>    
<a onmouseover="Tip('content3')" class="">Basic text3</a>    
<a onmouseover="Tip('content4')" class="">Basic text4</a>
```

Each hyperlinks calls the function with a different argument. I got this as my JS:

```
function Tip() {
  var content = arguments[0];
  $("#results").html("Tip function: "+content);
  return content;
}

$(document).ready(function()
{  
   Tip();
   $("#results2").html("Ready function: "+content); // How do I get the content value in this function??

});
```

Now I wonder is it possible to use the `var content` variable within my function `Tip()` inside the ready function?

Please note that I know using inline Javascript code is not recommended anymore but I am restricted to use that (due to previous implementations). Therefore the implementation of the `onmouseover` must stay intact.

example here: [CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gpEGNy)

Comment: The Tip() call in ready function is of no use as 1) no args are passed,, 2) Return Value is not captured.. Instead Try Using Global Variable

Answer (score 2):

First of all, there are some changes to function is needed.

```
function Tip(argument) {
    var content = argument;
    $("#results").html("Tip function: " + content);
    return content;
}
```

Using function directly.

```
$("#results2").html("Ready function: " + Tip('Pass something.'));
```

or using local variable.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var content = Tip('Pass something.');
    $("#results2").html("Ready function: " + content);
});
```

or using global variable.

```
var content;
function Tip(argument) {
    content = argument;
    $("#results").html("Tip function: " + content);
    return content;
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    Tip('Pass something');
    $("#results2").html("Ready function: " + content);
});
```

Comment: But we diidn't pass any Args to Tip() in your Direct Method & local variable Method, Won't that return undefined

Comment: @Danton yes you are right. The function calling has some issues. I didn't understand the deal with arguments[0]. It must be something to do with data attribute perhaps?

Comment: The arguments object is an Array-like object corresponding to the arguments passed to a function. @https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments

Answer (score 0):

try this way.

```
var objTest = {
    content : null,
    Tip: function(arg) {
        this.content = arg;
        $("#results").html("Tip function: " + this.content);
    },
    getContent : function(){

        return this.content;

    }
}


$(document).ready(function()
{  
   var content = objTest.getContent();
   $("#results2").html("Ready function: "+content); // How do I get the content value in this function??

});


function Tip(argument){

    objTest.Tip(argument);
}


<a onmouseover="Tip('content1')" class="">Basic text1</a>    
<a onmouseover="Tip('content2')" class="">Basic text2</a>    
<a onmouseover="Tip('content3')" class="">Basic text3</a>    
<a onmouseover="Tip('content4')" class="">Basic text4</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, here's a cheap but quick trick i usually use `.data()`

whenever you wish to store the value of a variable, store it in:

```
$("body").data("my_content", content); //Setter
```

& retrieve similarly:

```
$("body").data("my_content"); //Getter
```

There are many code techniques but i prefer this one as the content is not visible in the DOM hence can be used for **temporary manipulations**